# how to load a component in Lib or Vendor files

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

i am working on a cakephp 2.3. i want to load Email component into my class which is in Lib folder. same case for Vendor files too at the moment what i am doing is this..

```
App::uses('EmailComponent', 'Controller/Component');
class Email { 

public static function sendemail($toEmail,$template,$subject) {
$this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
                            'port'=>'25',
                            'timeout'=>'30',

                            'host' => 'host',
                            'username'=>'username',
                            'password'=>'password'
                        );


        $this->Email->template = $template;
                        $this->Email->from    = 'no-reply@hello.com';
                        $this->Email->to      = $toEmail;
                        $this->Email->subject = $subject;
                        $this->Email->sendAs = 'both';

                        $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';

                        $this->Email->send();



    }
```

i am not able to use `$this`.. i am getting this error

**$this when not in object context**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do that, components are controller "extensions", they are not ment to be used without them.

For emailing purposes use the [**`CakeEmail` class**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html) (the E-Mail component is deprecated anyways).

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

// ...

$Email = new CakeEmail(array(
    'port'      => 25,
    'timeout'   => 30,
    'host'      => 'host',
    'username'  => 'username',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
));

$Email->template($template)
      ->emailFormat('both')
      ->from('no-reply@hello.com')
      ->to($toEmail)
      ->subject($subject)
      ->send();
```

Comment: thaknyou.. do i use this in my classes which are in Lib folder ?

Comment: @hellosheikh You can use the `CakeEmail` class wherever you want, so yes, use it in your libraries.

Answer (score 0):

$this can be use in class for their on variables and method define within class
In cakephp $this is used in controller when the $components array is defined within controller.

Try this

```
$email = EmailComponent();
$email->$smtpOptions= array();
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer.error is coming after using your code .. here it is  "Call to undefined function EmailComponent();"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this in one of my `Lib` classes with Cake 3 using the following...

```
$oRegistry  = new ComponentRegistry();
$oComponent = $oRegistry->load('PluginName.ComponentName');
```

I'm unsure if this creates any kinda discord with the state with the app's component registry; but, for my purposes, it seems to work.

Hope this helps someone :)